# MPAndroidChart: Barchart Y Axis Animaion starting from 0

Tags: mpandroidchart

I'm testing MPAndroidChart and I'm trying to setup its initial animation.

Since my data can be shown in a closed range of values, I'm setting the BarChart Y axis to a minimum and a maximum value programmatically using `setAxisMinimum()` and `setAxisMaximum()`. After that, I animate the graph using `animateY(1000, Easing.EaseInOutExpo)`.

The problem is, as stated in some issues at GitHub, is that the animations are always drawn from zero, so there's a not-so-nice delay from calling animateY and the bars actually showing up.

Back in 2015, the developer used some code to solve this [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/1242), but it only works for linechart and actually there are some methods that might not exist right now.

Has anyone ever found a custom solution for this?